# Why would I call new without storing the ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, placement-new

Today I was reading though some source code and I encountered this

```
Pool<C> *pool = accomodate_component<C>();
new(pool->get(id.index())) C(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
```

And this line confused me

```
new(pool->get(id.index())) C(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
```

I didn't even think that it was legal C++. As it turns out `pool->get(id.index())` returns a size which told me that it could be possible to tell C++ explicitly how much size it should allocate.

I looked it up and yes it is defined that way `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );`

Now I know that this is legal C++ but what I don't know is its purpose.

Why would I ever call `new(size) Foo();`. Shouldn't this be a memory leak? And isn't it completely pointless? If I don't have the ptr how I would ever access it?

Comment: [Placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html).

Comment: its placement new. they don't store the pointer because they know where they placed the object. this form of new don't actually allocate memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is calling placement `new` which places an object into the location specified in parenthesis. With generalized `union`s accommodating class types I'd expect placement `new` to be more widely used: to change the tag to a class type you'll need to construct the object, probably using placement `new` (obviously, after manually destroying any object previously located in that spot, if any).

Since the location of the `new`ed object with placement `new` is readily known, there won't be any need to capture its address. Since the only way for placement `new` to fail is to have an exception thrown from the newly created object's constructor, there is also no point in checking the result.

Comment: Could you elaborate or point to something explaining what you said about using placement new for generalized unions? I see the same technique being used [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-types#generalized-unions) but I don't see why you need `case Tag::text: new(&s)(w.s); break;` instead of just case `Tag::text: s = w.s; break;`

Comment: @Pradhan: wouldn't that be a separate question...? The short answer is this: when the tag is changed, there is no object at that location. However, assignment assumes that the target object has set up appropriate invariants. It is the same difference between construction and assignment you have for raw memory.